# How is CPU usage calculated in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

Here's an image taken from Grafana which shows the CPU usage, requests and limits, as well as throttling, for a pod running in a K8s cluster.

[image]

As you can see, the CPU usage of the pod is very low compared to the requests and limits. However, there is around 25% of CPU throttling.

Here are my questions:

1. How is the CPU usage (yellow) calculated?
2. How is the ~25% CPU throttling (green) calculated?
3. How is it possible that the CPU throttles when the allocated resources for the pod are so much higher than the usage?

Extra info:

The yellow is showing `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`.
The green is `container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total / container_cpu_cfs_periods_total`

Comment: those calculations come from the query against your data source. No one can tell you how this is calculated. The formala is written in the query. Have a look there.

Comment: Please see the extra info